# List comprehensions in Python with mutable state between iterations

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have something which is an awful lot like a list comprehension in Python, except that it shares mutable state between iterations. Is there any way to do it with a list comprehension?

```
def f(x):
    """ 5-bit LFSR """
    return (x >> 1) ^ (0x12*(x&1))

def batch(f, x, n):
    result = [x]
    for _ in xrange(1,n):
        x = f(x)
        result.append(x)
    return result

batch(f, 1, 5)
```

which returns `[1, 18, 9, 22, 11]`. Here the important thing is the `batch` function, not `f(x)` which is here just a simple example to illustrate the issue.

Alternatively I could implement using a generator:

```
def batch(f, x, n):
    yield x
    for _ in xrange(1,n):
        x = f(x)
        yield x

list(batch(f, 1, 5))
```

But it smells a little awkward. What I'm looking for is something like this...

```
batch = [??? for _ in xrange(n)]
```

Comment: this smells suspiciously like one of those pesky Haskell monads would be useful, if I could only understand it.

Comment: "except that it shares mutable state between iterations. Is there any way to do it with a list comprehension" there might be some hacky way, but if it invovles mutating state, then it probably **shouldn't be a list-comprehension**

Comment: Also, "sharing mutable state between iterations" doesn't sound like anything in Haskell.

Comment: no, but stateful monads does

Comment: You could define a recursive generator using `yield from`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Deliberately no. Eventually they put in `itertools.accumulate`, which is the closest thing to an Officially Recommended way to implement recurrence relations in a functional manner, but it doesn't exist on 2.7. You could copy the "roughly equivalent to" Python implementation from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) if you want.

Answer (score 24):

> Is there any way to do it with a list comprehension?
>
> What I'm looking for is something like this...
>
> ```
> batch = [??? for _ in xrange(n)]
> ```

Sure, no problem:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> n = 5
>>> [prev.append(f(prev[0])) or prev.pop(0) for prev in [[x]] for _ in xrange(n)]
[1, 18, 9, 22, 11]
```

## Note: This is a bad idea. <sup><sub><sub>(I pretty much only did this because user2357112 said there is no way)</sub></sub></sup>

Comment: Holy hell that's sneaky.

Comment: While this is probably the cleanest, best-encapsulated form of state variables in a list comprehension I've seen (no leakage of the state variable into the surrounding scope, at least on Python 3), there's still a reason I didn't post anything like this: every instance of this kind of code on Stack Overflow, getting upvotes, increases the risk that people will think this kind of thing is a good idea and actually use it in their code.

Comment: @user2357112 Better now? :-)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Just figured out another neat way, it just doesn't have that required format with `xrange` at the end: `[q.append(f(x)) or x for q in [[x]] for x in q if len(q) <= n]`. Which one is sneakier? :-)

Comment: A little late but could anyone provide some insight as to why using code like this would be bad practice?

Comment: @evantkchong: Comprehensions and generator expressions are functional constructs (as in functional programming). They're intended to consume an input iterable, an item at a time, applying a filter and/or transform per item, with no side-effects or behaviors dependent on any mutable state aside from the item itself. Reasonable people expect them to behave this way, and every violation of that rule makes your code harder to read (a problem even if these conventions didn't exist, because forcing mutable state into the function gets *ugly* as you can see) and harder to maintain.

Comment: Functional programming tends to avoid mutable state entirely; obviously Python isn't a functional programming language, but the conventions around functional constructs exist for a reason, to make code behave in a predictable manner without every reader having to look for "gotchas". Even for expert Python programmers (I consider myself one), it takes *far* longer to parse this monstrosity than it would to read any reasonable listcomp.

Answer (score 4):

You *could* do this in a single line, using e.g. `reduce` (or `functools.reduce` in Python 3):

```
>>> f = lambda x: (x >> 1) ^ (0x12*(x&1))
>>> x, n = 1, 5
>>> functools.reduce(lambda lst, _: lst + [f(lst[-1])], range(1, n), [x])
[1, 18, 9, 22, 11]
```

But this is not only ugly, but also inefficient, as it will create a new list in each iteration. Or in a similar fashion to Stefan's approach, without creating intermediate lists:

```
>>> functools.reduce(lambda lst, _: lst.append(f(lst[-1])) or lst, range(1, n), [x])
[1, 18, 9, 22, 11]
```

Or, as already hinted in the other answer, you could use `itertools.accumulate`, which is a lot better, but still a bit of a mis-use, as it actually expects a binary function, whereas here we use neither the second parameter, nor the actual iterable passed into the function, except for the very first value.

```
>>> list(itertools.accumulate([x] * n, lambda y, _: f(y)))
[1, 18, 9, 22, 11]
```

Comment: While I consider using `itertools.accumulate` for this to be ugly, recurrence relations are explicitly listed as a use case in the [`accumulate` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate), with example code.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Good point, fixed, but that makes it even uglier.

Comment: @tobias_k Well then make it *prettier* instead :-). If you followed the documentation, you'd use `repeat(x, n)`. And since you're willing to create a list, you could simply use `[x] * n`.

Comment: For `reduce` you could also use `lst.__iadd__([f(lst[-1])])`, though I prefer the `append`+`or lst` (despite it being three characters longer! :-)

Comment: Ha, how about: `reduce(lambda lst, _: lst.append(f(lst[-1])) or lst, [[x]] * n)`. I actually laughed about this one... using the common `[[x]] * n` 2D-list gotcha... but it's ok here because the repeated references are ignored... I think that's just beautiful.