# How to create a list comprehension for this for loop

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to use list comprehension to replace this for loop.  My list is

```
test_list = [3, 4, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, 8, 12, 14, 1, 6, 7, 3, 7, 8, 3, 3, 7]
```

The function is

```
import numpy as np
def ema(x, n):
    x = np.array(x)
    emaint = np.zeros(len(x))
    k = 2 / float(n + 1)

    emaint[0:n] = np.average(x[:n])

    for i in range(n, len(x)):
        emaint[i] = (x[i] * k) + (emaint[i - 1] * (1 - k))

    return emaint
```

The result for if I call ema(test_list, 5) will be

```
[4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.53333333 5.35555556 6.23703704 8.15802469 10.10534979 7.0702332 6.7134888 6.80899253 5.53932835 6.0262189 6.68414594 5.45609729 4.63739819 5.42493213]
```

I have tried this

```
import numpy as np
def ema_compr(x, n):
    x = np.array(x)
    emaint = np.zeros(len(x))
    k = 2 / float(n + 1)

    emaint[0:n] = np.average(x[:n])

    emaint[n:] = [(x[i] * k) + (emaint[i - 1] * (1 - k)) for i in range(n, len(x))]

    return emaint
```

however the result is different if I call ema_compr(test_list, 5):

```
[4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.8 4.53333333 2.33333333 2.66666667 4. 4.66666667 0.33333333 2. 2.33333333 1. 2.33333333 2.66666667 1. 1. 2.33333333]
```

1. I would like if it is possible to get a list comprehension.
2. Is the result of the list comprehension different because I am tying to access a non-created element?

Comment: what are the values for x and n. i think x is the "test_list". how about n?

Comment: He says in his question what the result of `ema_compr(test_list, 5)` is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your loop needs to keep a running state it cannot cleanly be transformed into a list comprehension, although [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803229/7207392) exist.

So if you want "something like" a list comprehension I recommend the next best thing: an accumulator.

```
from itertools import accumulate

def ema(x, n):
    xx = n*[sum(x[:n])/n] + x[n:]
    p, q = 2 / (n+1), (n-1) / (n+1)
    return list(accumulate(xx, lambda a, b: q*a + p*b))
```

Gives:

```
ema(test_list, 5)
# [4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.533333333333333, 5.355555555555555, 6.2370370370370365, 8.158024691358024, 10.105349794238682, 7.070233196159121, 6.713488797439414, 6.808992531626275, 5.539328354417517, 6.026218902945011, 6.684145935296673, 5.456097290197782, 4.637398193465188, 5.424932128976792]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just using the `ewma` function in Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
def ema(x, n):
    pd_x = pd.Series(x)
    pd_x[:n] = pd_x[:n].mean()
    return pd.ewma(pd_x, span=n, adjust=False).as_matrix()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , you need to specify the indices there :

```
import numpy as np
test_list = [3, 4, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, 8, 12, 14, 1, 6, 7, 3, 7, 8, 3, 3, 7]

def ema(x, n):
    x = np.array(x)
    emaint = np.zeros(len(x))
    k = 2 / float(n + 1)

    emaint[0:n] = np.average(x[:n])

    for i in range(n, len(x)):
        [emaint.__setitem__(i, ((x[i] * k) + (emaint[i - 1] * (1 - k)))) for i in range(n, len(x))]

    return emaint


print(ema(test_list, 5))
```

output:

```
[  4.8          4.8          4.8          4.8          4.8          4.53333333
   5.35555556   6.23703704   8.15802469  10.10534979   7.0702332
   6.7134888    6.80899253   5.53932835   6.0262189    6.68414594
   5.45609729   4.63739819   5.42493213]
```

Answer (score 0):

In your list comprehension , you are trying to use index `emaint[i-1]` with out saving the array. In list comprehension it will be saved once it iterates through entire array

You can write for loop like this to set the element and can go to next iteration ( this is almost like your first solution)

```
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    if i<=n:
        emaint[i]=np.average(x[:n])
    else:
        emaint[i]=((x[i] * k) + (emaint[i - 1] * (1 - k)))
```

Or as suggested by Sebastian you can use Pandas

Comment: Thank you. You are right on the spot, I was trying to avoid the if.. else and your answer was my starting point. As I am trying to improve the speed to graph, I move the first part outside of the loop.  I try @sebastian answer but is a bit slower. I guess I should mention the speed factor in my question.