# Reduce increments in array values to 1

Tags: python, list, numpy

I am trying to create a list (say `B`) which increments only when there is a difference in values of another list (say `A`), for example:

`[1,1,2,2,4,4]` to `[0,0,1,1,2,2]` or

`[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4]` to `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1]` etc.

The following code does it:

```
boxes=[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4]
positions=[0]
position=0
for psn,box in list(enumerate(boxes))[:-1]:
    if boxes[psn+1]-box ==0:
        increment=0
    else:
        increment=1
    position=position+increment
    positions.append(position)
print(positions)
```

Can anybody give suggestions to do it using list comprehensions (preferable using `lambda` functions)?

Comment: Thank you so much, but the motive is to know how it can be done using lamda functions.

Comment: Actually, I misunderstood. `numpy.diff` is not what you're looking for.

Comment: It's not going to be easy (without side-effects or nested loops) to do this using a list comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a way using `nummpy`:

```
a = [1,1,2,2,4,4]
[0] + np.cumsum(np.clip(np.diff(a), 0, 1)).tolist()
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Or for the other example:

```
a = [1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4]
[0] + np.cumsum(np.clip(np.diff(a), 0, 1)).tolist()
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

**Details**

```
a = [1,1,2,2,4,4]
```

Get the first difference of the array with [`np.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html)

```
np.diff(a)
array([0, 1, 0, 2, 0])
```

And use [`np.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) to limit the values between `0` and `1`:

```
np.clip(np.diff(a), 0, 1)
array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

Finally take the [`np.cumsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) and add a `0` at the beginning as the difference will give you an array of length `n-1`:

```
[0] + np.cumsum(np.clip(np.diff(a), 0, 1)).tolist()
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1,1,2,2,4,4]

result = [i for i, (_, group) in enumerate(groupby(a)) for _ in group]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

I see numpy solutions, so here we go.

`digitize`

```
np.digitize(A, np.unique(A)) - 1
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

`factorize`

```
import pandas 
pd.factorize(A)[0]
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

`groupby` and `ngroup`

```
pd.Series(A).groupby(A).ngroup()

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    1
5    1
6    1
7    1
dtype: int64
```

---

`unique`

```
np.unique(A, return_inverse=True)[1]
# array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1])
```

---

Using list comprehension with `itertools.accumulate`:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import add

list(accumulate([0] + [x != y for x, y in zip(A, A[1:])], add))
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this with a traditional list comprehensions because they can't [share a mutable state between iterations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47803002/list-comprehensions-in-python-with-mutable-state-between-iterations/47803229).

In this case, using `itertools.groupby`, `numpy`, or a plain python loop (as in your code) is recommended.

BUT if you really wanted to use a list comprehension, one way would be to rely side effects.

For example:

```
boxes=[1,1,1,1,4,4,4,4]
positions = [0]
throwaway = [
    positions.append(positions[-1] + 0 if boxes[psn+1]-box == 0 else 1) 
    for psn, box in enumerate(boxes[:-1])
]
print(positions)
#[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

You are using the list comprehension to create a list called `throwaway`, but the actual contents of `throwaway` are not useful at all. We use the iterations to call `append` on `positions`. Since `append` returns `None`, the following is the actual result of the list comprehension.

```
print(throwaway)
#[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

However, relying on the side effects like this is not considered good practice.

Answer (score 2):

Method using `zip` and list comprehension and slicing

```
a = [1,1,2,2,4,4]
increments = [bool(i[1]-i[0]) for i in zip(a,a[1:])]
b = [sum(increments[:i]) for i in range(len(increments)+1)]
print(b) #prints [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Explanation: this solution, rely on that in Python:

any number other than `0` (or `0.0`) is evaluated as `True` when feed to `bool` function

when such need arises `True` and `False` values are turned into `1` and `0` respectively

how `sum` function works: in reality something like `sum([3,4])` means calculate `0+3+4` thus `sum([True,True])` means calculate `0+True+True`, which is translated into `0+1+1`